# Get total records of children from connected table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 5.5, but for this solution it would be same as for MySQL. I have two tables, first one contains galleries and second one contains info about files within each gallery. This is example of the table `gallery`:

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | name  | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  | test1 | ... |
| 2  | test2 | ... |
| 3  | test3 | ... |
| 4  | test4 | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
```

This is example of the table `gallery_items`:

```
+----+------+------------+-----+
| id | file | gallery_id | ... |
+----+------+------------+-----+
| 1  | img1 | 3          | ... |
| 2  | img2 | 2          | ... |
| 3  | img3 | 2          | ... |
| 4  | img4 | 1          | ... |
+----+------+------------+-----+
```

So I tried this code:

```
SELECT gallery.*, COUNT(gallery_items.id) AS items FROM gallery JOIN gallery_items WHERE gallery_items.gallery_id = gallery.id;
```

Well, I'm not really good with databases, so this is why I'm asking for help. This is my expected result:

```
+----+-------+-------+-----+
| id | name  | items | ... |
+----+-------+-------+-----+
| 1  | test1 | 1     | ... |
| 2  | test2 | 2     | ... |
| 3  | test3 | 1     | ... |
| 4  | test4 | 0     | ... |
+----+-------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you will need to `GROUP BY` in order for a `COUNT` to work

```
SELECT gallery.*, COUNT(gallery_items.id) AS items FROM gallery 
LEFT JOIN gallery_items ON gallery_items.gallery_id = gallery.id
GROUP BY gallery.id, gallery.name
```

Comment: I have never used `GROUP BY` before, thanks a lot! Also I changed `WHERE` to `ON`, because it doesn't worked with `WHERE`. Probably only in the MariaDB, don't know about others.

Answer (score 1):

**Description**  You may use the following query

```
SELECT
  g.*,COUNT(gi.id) AS items
FROM
  gallery g
LEFT JOIN gallery_items gi
ON g.id = gi.gallery_id
GROUP BY g.id;
```